# Dynamically Loading Controllers and ng-include

Tags: angularjs

At the moment I have an app that has a sidebar, and the sidebar loads different html templates using `ng-include` based on what operation the user chooses to do. It's a map related app, so for example, if the user selects the 'Add Leg' button it will load the `add_leg.html` template into the sidebar using `ng-include`:

```
// The Javascript code:
$scope.addLeg = function() {
    $scope.sidebar = true;
    $scope.sidebar_template = '/partials/legs/add_leg.html';    
}

// Simplified example of HTML:
<html>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <a ng-click="addLeg()">Add Leg</a>
    <a ng-click="addRoute()">Add Route</a>
    <a ng-click="editLeg()">Edit Leg</a>
    <a ng-click="editRoute()">Edit Route</a>
    ...

    <div id="sidebar" ng-class="{'sidebar-hidden': sidebar == false}">
        <div ng-include src="sidebar_template"></div>
    </div>

    <google-map></google-map>
</div>
```

This is all well and good and works as desired, but at the moment my app is only using one controller (`MainCtrl` in `js/controllers.js`) and it's starting to get really cluttered. I've got a lot of methods now because the apps functionality is expanding. I'd like to split my controller up into multiple controllers whilst retaining this sidebar functionality.

I want to have `MainCtrl` as the main controller that controls the loading of the sidebar template (by changing the `sidebar_template` variable that points to the file destination), and I want it to control some of the global map related methods (like fetching suburb names from coordinates, etc).

I've tried to split it like so:

```
controllers/js/main.js - MainCtrl
controllers/js/legs.js - LegCtrl
controllers/js/routes.js - RouteCtrl
```

I want the `LegCtrl` and `RouteCtrl` to inherit the `MainCtrl` so I can access its scope and methods, that's all fine. But now the problem is how do I dynamically load the controller onto the sidebar div based on what functionality is required. Originally all of my methods were in `MainCtrl`, and that's on the wrapper div that surrounds the sidebar div (see above again for an example), so it wasn't a problem.

For example, say I press the 'Add Leg' button, it's going to need to call `addLeg` in `LegCtrl`, but `LegCtrl` isn't loaded on the app, so it doesn't have access to the method. I could keep `addLeg()` inside the `MainCtrl`, and have it change the `sidebar_template` variable to load the template, but nothing in the template will work because it is calling methods from inside the `LegCtrl` now.

I need to somehow dynamically load the controller on the sidebar's `ng-include` div, something like this perhaps:

```
// MainCtrl
$scope.addLeg = function() {
    $scope.required_controller = LegCtrl;

    $scope.sidebar = true;
    $scope.sidebar_template = '/partials/legs/add_leg.html';    

    LegCtrl.addLeg();
}

<div id="sidebar" ng-class="{'sidebar-hidden': sidebar == false}">
    <div ng-include src="sidebar_template" ng-controller="{{required_controller}}"></div>
</div>
```

In the non-working example above you can see a possible solution I've thought of, but I need `LegCtrl`to be the actual controller function, not an object (for `ng-controller` to work). I also need some way to call `addLeg` on the `LegCtrl` from the `MainCtrl.addLeg` (perhaps using broadcast?).

If anyone can point me in the right direction that'd be great. Sorry for the huge post, it needed a bit of explaining to make it coherent. Hopefully it makes sense. Thanks.

**Update:** I think I've found a solution using a service to act as the navigation control (it will load the relevant templates and broadcast an event to the new controller being dynamically loaded to tell it what function to execute):

http://plnkr.co/edit/Tjyn1OiVvToNntPBoH58?p=preview

Just trying to test this idea out now, but the broadcast `.on` doesn't work. I think it's because the broadcast fires before the template loads. How can I fix this? Is this a good solution for what I'm doing?

Comment: I saw your plunker and have edited it to include to console messages. It will show you that event is published first and then listener starts listening. This happens because every thing is lazy loaded in angular app. http://plnkr.co/edit/rWZ3x2Jzk9EV3OpD1HF1?p=preview

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If i have understood you correctly what you can try would be to create a template view specifically to create a new leg.

From the main controller implement some logic to show the template

```
$scope.addLeg=function() {
   $scope.showAddLeg=true;
}
```

The AddLeg template view would load the controller and hence provide a mechanism to actually add new leg. The template would look like

```
<script type="text/ng-template" class="template" id="addLegTemplate">
    <div ng-controller='LegsController'>
    <!--html for adding a new leg-->
    </div>
</script>
```

You can include this template inside you main html using ng-if + ng-include.

```
<div ng-if='showAddLeg'><div ng-include='addLegTemplate'/></div>
```

Basically you can create multiple view and bind to same controller (but instance would differ). In this case the `LegsController` can be binded to multiple views to support the complete functionality.

Comment: The problem with this is if I'm loading new templates related to leg functionality (i.e. maybe on the addLeg template is a button to load the editLeg template), when they switch templates it will have its own controller definition in the new controller (and thus lose scope and all state variables will be lost).

Comment: You can share model by keeping it outside the controllers and passing it as part of ng-init.

Comment: There are multiple option i see. `ng-include` can take a onLoad function and there is an event on template loading in ng-include too. Try it. If nothing works you can always broadcast your message within a $timeout function, with a delay.

Answer (score 5):

I like this data driven scenario, just manipulate the rows in the templates:

```
$scope.templates = [
    { name: 'include1.html', url: 'partials/include1.html' }
];
$scope.addTemplate = function(name, url) {
    $scope.templates.push({ name: name, url: url });
};
```

and the markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="template in templates" ng-include="template.url"></div>
```

To add or remove views, just modify the templates et voila!  If you need more controller code, then you can include a link to the script in the include.  I guess there may be complications with binding to data in the partial view itself, but $compile should resolve those.

Answer (score 4):

I've forked your plunkr demo into one that I believe does what you're looking for:  http://plnkr.co/edit/whsjBT?p=preview

This demonstrates an event being broadcast from one controller to another AFTER the 2nd controller (`LegCtrl` in our example here) is loaded via `ng-include` and passing it data.

I used `$includeContentLoaded` event from [`ng-include`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) to delay broadcasting the event until angular reports that `add_leg.html` is loaded.   Also I think there were some issues with how you were using `$broadcast()`... it's first parameter should be the same as the one used in `$on()` in `LegCtrl`

Another idea to consider is simply using your `Navigation` service itself to share state between the controllers if that's appropriate in your scenario.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch!