# Different Menu items for different user roles in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5, jwt

I am creating a web app in Angular.js. I have to show different menu items for different users (Non-Logged Users, Non-Admin Logged In Users, Admin Users).

My initial approach was that I will send the API request along with a [JWT token](https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps), and based on that I can extract the user id (if present) and then perform processing based on whether the user is admin type or not. 
For e.g. 
let us say that I have 3 partials in total(Actually I have 57 !!)

1st partial is for logging in user.

2nd partial is for app function.

3rd partial is for app admin page.

Now for non Logged in user , he could see only 1st partial. Once the user has logged in he could see 2nd one as well. And if he is admin user he could see the third one as well.

Now for non logged in user, he should

But issues arise with how to load controllers, partials and CSSfor the menu items?

I am scratching my head, with no success at present.

Comment: css shouldn't be an issue , what specific problems are there regarding controllers? Question is a bit too broad without narrowing down some specifcs

Comment: I think this answer applies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801988/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-ng-include

Comment: @charlietfl-I have edited the question hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ngShow directive! ng-show shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ng-show attribute. I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/boglab/n7yfLhmb/2/) for you also.

```
<button class="btnEdit" ng-show="user.type=='admin'">Edit Item</button>
```

Please look in the AngularJS documentation for a detailed description of [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).

**Update**
One important note: If you do this, dont forget to check always in codebehind if the executing user of a command really has the permissions to do this. Cause angular variables can be changes e.g. in borwsers console by users.